# regex split string by specific values

Tags: regex, split, expression

Trying to split a string by specific characters and values with a regex expression.

I have the following string for example:

```
abc.def.ghi:wxyz_1234
```

I would like to get both '**wxyz**' and '**1234**'.

i.e. the string between ':' and '_' and the string after '_'

Cheers!

Answer (score 3):

### Method 1

Maybe,

```
([^\s:_]+)_(\S+)
```

might work OK.

#### [RegEx Demo 1](https://regex101.com/r/tT53sO/1/)

---

### Method 2

With lookbehind, to create a left boundary for pre-underscore string:

```
(?<=:)([^_]+)_(.+)
```

#### [RegEx Demo 2](https://regex101.com/r/FhbEG1/1/)

#### Test

```
import re

string = '''
abc.def.ghi:wxyz_1234
abc.def.ghi:abcd_78910
abc.def.ghi: foo_baz123
'''

expression = r'([^\s:_]+)_(\S+)'

for i in re.findall(expression, string):
    print(i[0])
    print(i[1])
```

#### Output

```
wxyz
1234
abcd
78910
foo
baz123
```

---

If you wish to simplify/modify/explore the expression, it's been explained on the top right panel of [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/tT53sO/1/). If you'd like, you can also watch in [this link](https://regex101.com/r/tT53sO/1/debugger), how it would match against some sample inputs.

---

#### RegEx Circuit

[jex.im](https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=&re=%5E(a%7Cb)*%3F%24) visualizes regular expressions:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

```
string str = "abc.def.ghi:wxyz_1234";    
Regex rx = new Regex(":(.*)_(.*)");    
Match match = rx.Match(str);    
string first =match.Groups[1].Value;    
string second= match.Groups[2].Value;
```

Comment: could you explain what's going on here?  e.g. what language is this (the question doesn't specify any), maybe also a link to the docs, etc.

Comment: Liked you made it in one go...
@SamMason
Here are more details - https://regex101.com/r/KZCFkm/1

Comment: @Shneor sorry I don't understand your comment... the actual regex is acceptable, it's everything else e.g. lack of any explanation about what's going on and that your question didn't talk about wanting to do this in any specific language (hence why is this in C#?)

Comment: @SamMason 
I did not want any specific language. Just needed advise about the regex.
After having the correct regex, it doesn't really matter where and how I use it.

Comment: @Shneor yes, that was my point!  Darpan could have posted `:(.*)_(.*)` and it would have been just as useful

Answer (score 0):

I managed to create the following
Case A - `(?<=:)(.+)(?=_)`
Case B - `(?<=_).*`

Guess the options are endless...

Thanks for your assistance!